# Better way to parse XML using PHP to create hierarchy with data table in it

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I recently (2 weeks ago) started coding in PHP and today I ran into a problem and wondering if somebody can help/guide me.

I am getting xml data from a Web Service and want to render the data as show in below image

[image]

The fetched XML looks like this

```
 <pricesheets>
<pricesheet>            
    <buyinggroupname>China</buyinggroupname>
    <categoryname>Category B</categoryname>
    <currency>USD</currency>
    <discamt>39330.00</discamt>
    <productdesc>Product B description</productdesc>
    <prdouctId> Product B </productId>
</pricesheet>
<pricesheet>            
    <buyinggroupname>Asia</buyinggroupname>
    <categoryname>Category A</categoryname>
    <currency>USD</currency>
    <discamt>39330.00</discamt>
    <productdesc>Product A description</productdesc>
    <prodouctId> Product A </productId>
</pricesheet>   
</pricesheets>
```

The issue I am having is what's the best way to parse above XML so that I can render products based on 'buyinggroupname' and 'categoryname'. I can easily accomplish the collapse and expand feature once I know how to render the data.

Below is what I have done to achieve what I want. But I know for sure that my code is NOT efficient and scalable.

```
$xmldata;  // XML return by the webservice
$data = simplexml_load_string($xmldata);
$category_A_items = '';
$category_B_items = '';
foreach ($data as $object) {
  if($object->categoryname == 'Category A') { // Bad Idea : Hard coded category
      $category_A_items .= '<tr><td>'.$object->prdouctId.'</td><td>'. $object->productdesc. '</td><td>'. $object->discamt. '</td></tr>';
    }
  elseif($object->CATEGORYNAME == 'Category B') { // Bad Idea : Hard coded category
        $category_B_items .='<tr><td>'.$object->prdouctId. '</td><td>'. $object->productdesc. '</td><td>'. $object->discamt. '</td></tr>';                      
    }
}
//Render Category A items in table
 if(strlen($category_A_items) > 0) {
      echo '<h3>CAD</h3>';
      echo '<table><tr><th>Product Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Price</th></tr>';
      echo $cadItems;
      echo '</table>'. PHP_EOL;
  }
  //Render Category B items in table
  if(strlen($category_B_items) > 0) {
      echo '<h3>Breast Biopsy</h3>';
      echo '<table><tr><th>Product Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Price</th></tr>';
      echo $breastBiopsy;
      echo '</table>'. PHP_EOL;
  }
```

The above code only renders the data based on categories ( which are hard coded). Now what would be better way of doing the same so that I can render the data based on 'buyingroupname' and 'categoryname' without hard coding either of this two values in the php code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your XML is broken, see node <prdouctId> Product A </productId>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get an array of unique `<categoryname>`-nodes with xpath, then loop through it and select all `<pricesheet>`-nodes with that specific category, letting xpath do that job, again:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x);
$cat = array_unique($xml->xpath("//categoryname"));

foreach ($cat as $c) {
    echo "$c<br />";
    foreach ($xml->xpath("//pricesheet[categoryname='$c']") as $p) {
        echo $p->productId."<br />";
    }
}
```

see a live-demo @ http://codepad.viper-7.com/m9ruRU

Of course, you have to add code for creating tables...

Comment: Voila! that worked like charm. Thanks for your effort. You saved my day and plush I learned about the 'xpath'. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please update your live demo so that it  groups by 'buyinggroupname' also?. I tried but its not working correctly. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Putting the strings in arrays with variable keys lets PHP keep them organized for you, and you don't have to know any category names at all. I used multidimensional arrays so that each buyingroup has its categories inside it.  Then you loop through the arrays to make each table.  Let me know if you need more explanation.  I misunderstood your image the first time I saw it.

```
$xmldata;  // XML return by the webservice
$data = simplexml_load_string($xmldata);
$buyinggroups = array();
foreach ($data as $object) {
    if(isset($object->buyinggroupname) || isset($object->BUYINGGROUPNAME)) {
        if(isset($object->buyinggroupname)) {
            $name = $object->buyinggroupname;
        } else {
            $name = $object->BUYINGGROUPNAME;
        }
    }
    if(isset($object->categoryname) || isset($object->CATEGORYNAME)) {
        if(isset($object->categoryname)) {
            $category = $object->categoryname;
        } else {
            $category = $object->CATEGORYNAME;
        }
    }
    if(isset($category) && isset($name)) { //just making sure this row is OK
        if(!isset($buyinggroups[$name])) {
            $buyinggroups[$name] = array();  //initialize the outer array
        }
        if(!isset($buyinggroups[$name][$category])) {
            $buyinggroups[$name][$category] = '';  //this is like your previous $category_A_items
        }
        $buyinggroups[$name][$category] .= '<tr><td>'.$object->productId.'</td><td>'. $object->productdesc. '</td><td>'. $object->discamt. '</td></tr>';
    }
}


//Render all categories in lots of tables
//I am guessing at what HTML you want here; I don't think it's necessarily correct
echo '<table>'. PHP_EOL;
foreach($buyinggroups as $name=>$set) {
    echo '<tr><th colspan="2">'.$name.'</th></tr>'. PHP_EOL;
    echo '<tr><th> </th><td>';
    foreach($set as $category=>$rows) {
        echo '<table>'; 
        echo '<tr><th><h3>'.$category.'</h3></th>'. PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td><table><tr><th>Product Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Price</th></tr>';
        echo $rows;
        echo '</table>'. PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

**EDIT:**

This can't possibly be beyond your ability to debug.  You are getting everything you need in order to debug.  PHP tells you the line number and the error.  You google the error and find out what it means.  Then you go to that line number and see how what's there corresponds to the thing you googled.  In this case, I can tell you that "illegal offset type" means that you have an array key that is not a string or integer.  On those lines in the error messages, you have the array keys $name and $category.  Try var_dump($name) and var_dump($category) to find out what they actually are, or even var_dump($object) to find out how to get name and category out of the object.

Comment: thanks for your effort in answering this. I tried your solution and I am getting 'Illegal Offset' warning. I tried to debug it but probably its beyond my skill. Here is the link with your solution [link](http://codepad.viper-7.com/HGj2JL) in action. I made a small typo correction in your solution - the 'buyingroup is actually 'buyinggroup' with two g's.